# Cannot convert value of type 'Void' to expected argument type '() -> Void'

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to pass a function as a variable but keep getting this error.

The instance of a class with a function variable:

```
ViewOfSquares(square: self.game.squares[index], function: self.game.mutate(index: index))
```

The class itself:

```
struct ViewOfSquares: View {

@ObservedObject var square: Square
var function: () -> Void

var body: some View {
    
    ZStack {
        Button(action: self.function, label: {
            Text("")      
            
        })
              
    }}}
```

The method I'm passing (self.game.mutate):

```
func mutate(index: Int) -> Void {
   print("test")
        
}
```

Comment: You are not passing a function, you are calling a function and passing the result

Answer (score 2):

You are passing in the *output* of the `mutate` function, which is `Void`. Note that you also don't need to specify return types of `Void`.

Instead, you want to pass in the closure which runs the `mutate` function:

```
ViewOfSquares(square: self.game.squares[index], function: { self.game.mutate(index: index) })
```